# GWT, Elemental, Worker : null instance

Tags: java, gwt, worker

Using GWT and elemental, I have some problem with a null instance. Here is code:

```
import elemental.events.Event;
import elemental.events.EventListener;
import elemental.html.Window;
import elemental.html.Worker;

public void go()
{
    Window window=elemental.client.Browser.getWindow();
    Worker worker=window.newWorker("task.js");
    EventListener eventListener=new EventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("worker : "+worker+" eventListener : "+eventListener+" window : "+window);
    worker.setOnmessage(eventListener);
}
```

The display is:

```
worker : [object Worker] eventListener : mainpackage.client.MainClass$1@565f81ea window : [object Window]
```

So the worker is not null, but I have the error within setOnmessage:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) : Invoking an instance method on a null instance
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:80)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:64)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:60)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:304)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
at elemental.js.html.JsWorker$.setOnmessage$(JsWorker.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$.elemental_html_Worker_setOnmessage(JavaScriptObject.java)
at mainpackage.client.MainClass.go(MainClass.java:41)
at mainpackage.client.Testthread.onModuleLoad(Testthread.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why is there a null instance? How do I solve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) : Invoking an instance method on a null instance
```

This line has an Answer.

As you are trying to invoke

`worker.setOnmessage(eventListener);`

```
Worker worker=window.newWorker("task.js");
```

`worker` Object is NULL.

So please check whether your `newWorker` method is actually returning `Worker` object or not.

Comment: I do not understand why worker object is null. As I said display is worker : [object Worker]. So not null no? I add that

worker.postMessage("");

Does not show any error.

Comment: You are printing worker Object but make sure it has value or not.

Comment: So bad that null object is not just null as in C++. Admitting it's null, How could I make it not null ? The task.js is a the right place. The code of worker is the same that here http://www.instantshift.com/2013/11/19/html5-features-with-gwt-elemental/. Thanks for helping.

Comment: For that make sure your `.js` must be in same package as your class is or if not you need to give path like this for example 'window.newWorker("C:\\Folder\\worker.js");'